# not all tables were imported to my edmx

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, linq, edmx

I am working on JQuery Mobile project, using EDMX + LINQ to get sql queries.
After working with this for a while, i noticed that one of my connection tables was not imported to my data entity model, though i need to query this table now.

[Here is the table (marked in blue) that was not imported properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClGIo.png)

[Here you can see the table in model browser but not in the diagram, hence i can't use it in my LINQ queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W22J.png)

I guess it has to do something with the fact that it is a connection table and it doesn't stand on its own, so what can i do in this case if i still want to query this with LINQ and not SQL?

Comment: the navigation properties are on your Activities_TB and Users_TB so i wouldn't worry about the diagram.. as long as you can see Users_Activities_TB in your context class you're fine

Comment: The problem is that i can't query this table.
for example, i want to get all the activities that are related for specific user. 
when i try to do something like:
var userActivities = from uAct in dbEntity.UsersActivities_TB...
the table is not recognized.

Using simple join between Users_TB and Activities_TB will not be enough, because i need to know if this specific user has that specific activity,

Comment: if you want to know if a user has a specific activity you just use `dbEntity.Users_TB.Where(a => a.Activities_TB.Any(b => b.Act_Name == "Golf"));`  this would give you all uses that play golf.. Also to get all users that play golf you could use `dbEntity.Activities_TB.Where(a => a.Act_Name == 'Golf').Select(a => a.Users_TB);`

Comment: `Users_TB` will have a property that is `ICollection<Activities_TB>`  this will contain all of that user's activities.. `Activities_TB` will have a property that is  `ICollection<Users_TB>` that will have all users that are assigned to that activity

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that it's because your table does not have a primary key, it's two fields are both foreign keys to other tables.  I've run into similar problems with views/tables not importing.  It needs it's own primary key, something like User_Activities_TB_ID.

Comment: I double checked this, and both of these fields are primary and foreign keys.

Comment: From my experience, what I've suggested will make the table import into your model.  It's up to you if you want to try it, you can always revert your DB changes and refresh the model.

Comment: Just now i understood what you have meant:
right now i have 2 fields that are both primary and foreign keys. what do i need now to do is to add a third field which will be also a primary key, but will be unique only for this table? so in other words, in order to get a table imported to edmx, i must have at least one field which will be a primary key and will not be foreign key as well? correct me if i am wrong.
gonna check this now

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution I would try.  I've dealt with odd tables and views not importing before, and this seems to be one of the issues.  I'm sure there is some documentation somewhere on stuff like this, but this is just from my experience.